# Unable to get result from stdout with subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I need to get the result being displayed in the console after issuing a command.

**e.g.:** `H:/path/to/openssl.exe x509 -in H:/path/to/cert.pem -noout -subject`

This command produces values of an encrypted certificate when placed in an opened cmd.exe but I am unable to get the same result as a returned variable using the `subprocess` module.

So far I have attempted (where `cmd` is the e.g. above):

```
# checking if output is going to stderr
out = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
# attempt with Popen
out = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0]
# attempt with Popen not using communicate()
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out = p.stdout.read()
```

All the `print (out)` values are `b''`.

I have even broken the `cmd` into multiple `args` for both `check_output()` and `Popen()` such that it would look like: `["H:/path/to/openssl.exe", "x509 -in H:/path/to/cert.pem -noout -subject"]`.

I do have an alternative method to achieve the result, but that requires running a .bat file that contains the command: `start cmd /k "... > H:/path/to/temp.txt"` where the `...` is the command in question here. This redirects the .exe output to a temp file (for security purposes) which I delete after reading contents into a variable.

**Supporting information:**

If the first part of the command is run (the .exe) it opens custom console for that program. The remainder of the command is executed in that console and then that console closes. However if the whole command series is used in a cmd.exe console, the output is displayed in that console. Hence why the use of `" "` in my alternate method of a .bat as it issues it to the open console as a whole command.

Use of `subprocess.Popen(["cmd.exe"])` opens a console at `C:\Python36>` and I can issue the command in question and get the exact result I want. I cannot seem to grab it pythonically though. However, `subprocess.Popen(["cmd.exe", "H:/path/to/openssl.exe"])` does not execute the second command; opens a console but does not start the .exe console.

**Update:**

I was able to get a result, but I don't like how I got there. Is there a shorter way to do the following:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("H:/path/to/openssl.exe", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
# b for byte-type requirement
p.stdin.write(b"x509 -in H:/path/to/cert.pem -noout -subject")
p.stdin.close()
out = p.stdout.read()
```

I can also produce the result with:

`p = os.popen("start cmd /k H:/path/to/openssl.exe -in H:/path/to/cert.pem -noout -subject")`

Tried to add `.read()` to the above, but prints a blank line

Comment: General tip:  it's not secure to set `shell=True` in `Popen` arguments.  Try instead to pass `shlex.split(cmd)` as your first argument to `Popen`.

Comment: @Billy Still returning `b''`. I'm trying to figure out why even with a split command, `Popen()` is not executing the second command as described above in "Supporting information".

Comment: @Billy Updated question

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried storing the entire command as raw string and passing it with shell=True

`cmd = r'H:/path/to/openssl.exe x509 -in H:/path/to/cert.pem -noout -subject'
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out = p.communicate()
print(out[0]) #for std out
print(out[1]) # for std err`

Edit: This worked for me with stderr,

`print p.communicate()[1]`

`b'unable to load certificate\r\n3636:error:0D07209B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_
get_object:too long:./crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c:142:\r\n3636:error:0D068066:asn1 en
coding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:bad object header:./crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1281:
\r\n3636:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 erro
r:./crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:380:Type=X509\r\n3636:error:0906700D:PEM routines:PEM
_ASN1_read_bio:ASN1 lib:./crypto/pem/pem_oth.c:83:\r\n'`

Comment: Assuming you mean `print(out[0])` and `print(out[1])`. Yes I have and both return as `b''`. It is almost like the commands are not being executed sequentially. I've got a parallel problem post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44371876/why-is-popen-not-executing-next-command)

Comment: What is happening for me is that I am effectively running the openssl.exe, passing valid args and getting a return. However it doesn't seem to be going to the cmd.exe stdout; it is staying in the openssl.exe. I need to essential do `C:\Users\Me> H:/path/to/openssl.exe x509 -in H:/path/to/cert.pem -noout -subject` and grab that `stdout`; when I run through `Popen()` it produces a result but it is placed on a line before the CLI and not in `stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

i am not used to use python on windows, but try the following. Don't use `shell=True`, instead try with this cmd:

```
cmd = ["H:/path/to/openssl.exe", "x509", "-in", "H:/path/to/cert.pem", "-noout", "-subject"]
```

Comment: should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: This does not work as `Popen()` is not executing the next command in list