# Why is Popen("cmd.exe echo a", shell=True) not running "echo"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This leads to a bigger problem I am having [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44369460/unable-to-get-result-from-stdout-with-subprocess) with `Popen()`.

The following does not do what I thought it should:

```
x = subprocess.Popen("cmd.exe echo a", stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
print (x.stdout.read())
```

Returns the "title" message of the cmd console, but `echo a` is never executed.

Same with:

```
x = subprocess.Popen(["cmd.exe", "echo a"], stdout=PIPE)
print (x.stdout.read())
```

and

```
cmd = "cmd.exe echo a"
x = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=PIPE)
print (x.stdout.read())
```

End result is in open cmd terminal that prints the standard "Microsoft Windows version..." and a CLI position of `C:\Python36>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cmd.exe` requires the argument `/c` to precede a script being passed for execution:

```
x = subprocess.Popen(["cmd.exe", "/c", "echo a"], stdout=PIPE)
print (x.stdout.read())
```

Comment: Now what if I wanted the `stdout` of say `C:\Users\Me> C:\path\to\app.exe arg1 arg2`? If I open a cmd console and supply the .exe path and args, the output is produced to `stdout` but I cant seem to replicate with `subprocess` as outline in my link in the OP.

Answer (score 3):

The command processor `cmd.exe` is implicit when you specify `shell=True`.

```
>>> x = subprocess.Popen("echo a", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
>>> print (x.stdout.read())
a
```

By invoking it explicitly you fire up a nested command console, as if you had typed `cmd.exe` at the prompt. Its output doesn't go to `Popen()`'s pipe.